# PHP cUrl doesnt follow RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc, curl

I have 2 application, one is PHP and the other is .net MVC written in C#.
The PHP application sends cURL HTTP POST request to a HttpPost action in MVC app. The action is pretty simple but at the end of it I have RedirectToAction('someGetAction') which redirects the request to a HttpGet action within the same application. The redirect in MVC app works as expected, tested by various tools such as Postman and custom made tools. However, when I try to send the POST using cURL the request times out in the step RedirectToAction('someGetAction'). I can debug the post action fine, up to the point where the redirect to action is supposed to happen but nothing happens then.
Any ideas what could be the problem here?

Here is my cURL:

```
<?php
$data = 'someData=someData';
$header = array(
                'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
                'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)
);

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mvcApplicationUrl');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
echo 'finished';

?>
```

Comment: Interesting, because there is no magic at ASP.NET MVC Redirect, it will basically result in a simple http redirection. What if you would experiment with different results like `return Redirect("http://www.example.org");` or `Response.Redirect("http://www.example.org", endResponse: true); return null;` to check whether it's something specific to Routing?

Comment: Tried both suggestions, both timed out just like before.

Comment: OK so I have no idea. maybe you can try to listen to Http traffic using the Tool [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). You wil be able to examine HTTP Traffic in detail, maybe there's something wrong with the response

Answer (score 2):

You said

> The action is pretty simple but at the end of it I have
>   RedirectToAction('someGetAction') which redirects the request to a
>   HttpGet action within the same application.

No, it doesn't actually do that.

What it does is do send a HTTP 302 response to the client with a "Location" HTTP header which contains the URL to redirect to.

The client may **optionally** decide to make a new request to that URL. GUI Browsers generally do this automatically, as a user-friendly feature. Other HTTP clients such as cURL, generally do not - if you want to follow the redirect you have you read the header information yourself and write code to make a fresh request to the suggested URL.

The behaviour of `RedirectToAction` is documented here, mentioning the process I described above: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx and also a standard 302 response is described in general here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Anyway, if you are intending to make programmatic calls from one application to another application, you'd be better off exposing a Web API controller on the .NET side so the applications can exchange information in a machine friendly format such as JSON or XML, rather than trying to deal with a GUI application designed for human user via a browser.

Comment: I was irritated by the fact the OP wrote "the request times out" which didn't also make sense to me